# MIPS assembly: cannot store/print array elements

Tags: arrays, assembly, mips

The first part of my Mips project is reading 2 2x2 arrays with double-type elements. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong, but when I'm trying to print the second element of the first array (just to check if it's working) I'm getting just zero. Probably a stupid question, but any help would be much appreciated. Thanks

```
 .data

input1: .asciiz "a(1,1)="
input2: .asciiz "a(1,2)="
input3: .asciiz "a(2,1)="
input4: .asciiz "a(2,2)="

input5: .asciiz "b(1,1)="
input6: .asciiz "b(1,2)="
input7: .asciiz "b(2,1)="
input8: .asciiz "b(2,2)="

tableA: .space, 32
tableB: .space, 32
tableC: .space, 32

zeroasdouble: .double 0.0







.text

la $a0, tableA
la $a1, tableB
la $a2, tableC
l.d $f30, zeroasdouble

addi $t0, $zero, 0
addi $t1, $zero, 0
addi $t2, $zero, 0

add $t0, $a0, $zero   #tablea address goes to t0
add $t1, $a1, $zero   #tableb address goes to t1
add $t2, $a2, $zero   #tablec address goes to t2

#start reading values

addi, $v0, $zero, 4
la $a0, input1
syscall

addi $v0, $zero, 7
syscall
sdc1 $f0, 0($t0) ###### read float-store double in memory


addi, $v0, $zero, 4
la $a0, input2
syscall

addi $v0, $zero, 7
syscall
sdc1 $f0, 8($t0)#####

addi, $v0, $zero, 4
la $a0, input3
syscall

addi $v0, $zero, 7
syscall
sdc1 $f0, 16($t0)#####

addi, $v0, $zero, 4
la $a0, input4
syscall

addi $v0, $zero, 7
syscall
sdc1 $f0, 24($t0)##### table a filled-in

#fill-in table b

addi, $v0, $zero, 4
la $a0, input5
syscall

addi $v0, $zero, 7
syscall
sdc1 $f0, 0($t1)#####

addi, $v0, $zero, 4
la $a0, input6
syscall

addi $v0, $zero, 7
syscall
sdc1 $f0, 8($t1)#####

addi, $v0, $zero, 4
la $a0, input7
syscall

addi $v0, $zero, 7
syscall
sdc1 $f0, 16($t1)#####

addi, $v0, $zero, 4
la $a0, input8
syscall

addi $v0, $zero, 7
syscall
sdc1 $f0, 24($t1)#####

lwc1 $f12, 0($t0) ####delete test
li $v0, 3
syscall


addi $v0, $zero, 10
syscall
```

Comment: google: <name_of_your_platform/simulator> MIPS debugger  ... find some docs how to use debugger of your platform... see yourself by single stepping each instruction, which values are not as expected, and what is stored into memory. (this is essential for any further asm programming, so while somebody will maybe tell you your exact problem with this code, you will run into this situation again and again and SO is much more friendly toward questions where you can actually show particular state/instruction you don't understand, than generic "here are 20 lines of code not doing what I want")